# webclient used to make a request to server but returns ERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webclient

Using a `WebClient` to make a request to the server.

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string xmlString = web.DownloadString(partialUrl);
```

The `partialUrl` returns a valid URL, which if I use in a browser returns the correct XML list, but if ran from debug mode in Visual Studio it throws the error:

```
{System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   at Synchroniser.XML.GalwayPortal.Download_POS(String partialUrl, IInterpreter interpreter)
```

Answer (score 2):

From Your Error It seems that you are creating a web request with wrong url.

Please make sure that in web.DownloadString(partialUrl); url string must start with proper protocol like (http,https etc.)